# PyQGIS return Field

Tags: pyqgis, time

I have this layer:
[image]
I'd like to have a label that  changes in time, I have a function that gives back the current time in the same format as my field names but gives back a string, not a field.
[image]

What should the function give back so QGIS expressions could interpret it as a field?